# Can I use "as" instead of "because of" ? Would it be right?

Tags: usage, word-difference

For example,

> Air pollution is on the increase *as* many reasons.

Actually my sentence was

> Air pollution is on the increase *because of* many reasons . . .

but I replaced *'because of'* with *'as'*. Is it right?

Comment: I would prefer to use "for many reasons". If you absolutely want to use "as", may I suggest "as a result of many reasons", to keep the same meaning as "because". This is however a lot of words for very little effect.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, If I were you, I would replace "on the increase" with "increasing" because it sounds better.

In term of meaning, *as* also means *because* in some contexts. But they aren't always interchangeable. *Because of* is followed by a noun phrase or a gerund complement

> . . . *because of*  many reasons

*As* functions as a subordinate conjunction introduces a new subordinate clause.

> . . . *as* people in the country use an excessive amount of aerosol. . .

Comment: Ok, so you mean i can not use" as" instead of "because of"?  Sorry ,I ask question again because I did not get the point in your second example  ..  as people in the country ...

Comment: It could be anything @Maryprincess55321 The increase in eczema among teens increased as they use an excessive amount of aerosol deodorants. The chemicals in spray deodorants had to be modified as people use(d) an excessive amount of aerosols during that period and scientists felt it was a contributor to the hole in the ozone layer.

Comment: @Maryprincess55321 notice because of take a noun phrase complement, while as take a clause. That's the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

"As" can have several meanings.

- As described in user178049's answer it could mean "coincident with" (at the same time as); i.e., correlation rather than cause/effect.
- As used in my previous bullet to mean "in the manner of" or "similar to".
- It can also mean "because":  "You'd better do what the robber says as he has a gun."  (I would not expect someone to actually choose those words, just illustrating a case.)

But when it's used to mean "because", it is used more as a connector of two standalone pieces, like my example in the last bullet.  So in your examples, "because of" would be the technically correct version.

However, that is awkward.  In normal speech, someone would say "**for** many reasons".